# UIScrollview in a Custom UICollectionViewCell Not Working

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to get a `UIScrollView` to work correctly inside of a `UICollectionViewCell`.

The custom cell is being loaded in via a xib file and is a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. I had problems getting other controls working, such as a button and a gesture recognizer since the `UICollecitonView` doesn't seem to be passing any touches to the cells, but I got around those with gesture recognizers on the `UICollectionView` itself. The one remaining issue I have is the UIScrollViews...

The `UICollectionView` scrolls horizontally, and the `UIScrollView` in the cells scroll vertically. I've tried using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to scroll them, but that seems to disable the `UICollectionView's` ability to scroll.

Anybody have any thoughts?

EDIT: Got it!

So I had converted to a collection view from a previous third party library we were using before iOS6. Turns out the problem was with the xib files we were using for the cells. With the library before, the cells were just subclasses of UIViews. I changed the classes to subclass `UICollectionViewCell`, and updated the Custom Class. Turns out this was not enough. In order for touches to get passed to the cells I needed to actually had to drag in a new `UICollectionViewCell` from the Object library, copy over all the subviews and reconnect the `IBOutlets`. After this, it worked!

Comment: Have you looked into UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?

Comment: I have, and I've tried using gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: and still the additional pan recognizer overrides the default scrolling behaviour... Is there something else I should be using?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No problem with UISCrollView in UICollectionViewCell. Use StoryBoard and you'll scroll OK.
UIScrollView overlay UICollectionViewCell, so that didSelect work only when tap outside ScrollView and inside Cell (scrollView.frame < cell.frame).

If you want to implement tap or other gesture, just add it to UIScrollView in awakeFromNib

Refer code:

https://github.com/lequysang/github_zip/blob/master/CollectionViewWithCellScrollViewStoryBoard.zip

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in my code by making sure resizing of the scroll view happens on main thread.

My collection view is using nsfetchedresultscontroller that is using block calls to refresh selected cells.  On the first time a cell was selected the scrollview would not scroll.  However if you clicked on another cell and clicked back it would work fine.  The initial load of the cell seemed like size calc might not be where it needed to be on main thread to affect behavior.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell =  [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // resizeScrollViewMethod should be where scrollview content size > scroll view frame.
        [cell resizeScrollViewMethod];
    });
    return cell;
}

- (void) resizeScrollViewMethod {
    //Do your scrollview size calculation here
}
```